# Consultar el top 5 de cada mes con MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, sql

Tengo tres tablas con la siguiente estructura:

```
 CREATE TABLE northwind.empleado (
    id_empleado     INT         NOT NULL,
    nom_empleado    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE northwind.partida (
    num_pedido  VARCHAR(15)     NOT NULL,
    id_producto INT             NOT NULL,
    ventas      DECIMAL(12,2)   NOT NULL
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE northwind.pedido (
    num_pedido      VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    id_pedido       INT         NOT NULL,
    fecha_pedido    DATE        NOT NULL,
    id_empleado     INT         NOT NULL,
    id_cliente      INT         NOT NULL
);
```

Debo crear una consulta en MySQL que muestre los 5 empleados con más ventas de cada mes, pero hasta ahora únicamente he podido crear una consulta que me muestra las ventas de todos los empleados de cada mes.

Esta es la consulta:

```
SELECT MONTH(fecha_pedido) Mes, SUM(ventas) Ventas, nom_empleado Nombre FROM partida 
INNER JOIN pedido ON partida.num_pedido = pedido.num_pedido 
INNER JOIN empleado ON pedido.id_empleado = empleado.id_empleado 
GROUP BY Mes, Nombre 
ORDER BY Mes, Ventas;
```

Agradeceré muchísimo cualquier ayuda.

Comment: nos podes mostrar que intentaste?

Comment: Si, claro, disculpa.

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado a añadir a tu consulta una orden y un límite?

```
SELECT * FROM ‘nombre_tabla’ ORDER BY ‘campo_ordenar’ DESC LIMIT 5

Puedes probar a ordenar por Count('id_empleado').
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es incorrecta,  lo que quiere hacer el usuario es por cada mes seleccionar lo 5 empleados con más ventas por cada mes, los 5 empleados de enero, los empleados de febrero y así sucesivamente, lo que tu propones es que te devuelva los 5 empleados con más ventas sin tener en cuenta los meses